# How Do I change Font color/size/type PDF file resources using UIWebView for iPhone SDK V 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to display PDF file in iPhone SDK V 3.0. I am able to display PDF file. But I want to change its font size/type/color. PDF file also conatins images.

Is there any way to have change font size/color/type of PDF file using UIWebView?

If no then is other option is available to display PDF file instead of UIWebView?

Comment: The whole point of a PDF is that it maintains the fidelity of the original document!

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView does not give any controll on content which it is displaying, to the user. 
Through webview we cannot change any pdf contents font size or style.
We need to extract content from the pdf and change font and size..again render it as pdf and write to pdf file..then display on UIWebView.

Answer (score -2):

Try Stanza - you have to install Stanza apps for iPhone / iPod Touch and Stanza the desktop software (free). You'll have the chance to modify the font size, color, etc :)